# ArgoUML signal in activity diagram

Tags: concurrency, argouml, activity-diagram

I'm working on a activity diagram that shows model/view transitions. I've done a lot of class diagrams with ArgoUML and want to do this with ArgoUML, too.

For a user input I would usually use an input signal. In ArgoUML 0.34, I can not figure out how signals work. There is no input/output signal component.

How can I show listener events like user input or a model event that leads to an UI update?

It should look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of elements which are under pulldown menus instead of being directly on the tool bar.  The pulldown to the left of the Guard element on the toolbar has all the Events on it.  The default tool is the Call Event, but there's a Signal Event underneath as well.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. I've been unable to figure out the correct procedure to model input/output signals in ArgoUML.

I've copied the layout from the original post but wasn't able to change the shape of the symbols:

[image]